# Ruby: How can I make an arrayify! filter method to parse not-array objects(string, hash, integer) into array type

Tags: ruby, methods, filter

I want to define a method to parse parameter into array to avoid parameter is a string or other types not support loop, so I want to define a method like this:

```
    def arrayify_param!(param)

    end

    # After call arrayify_param! method, I can loop a string 

    str = 'abc'
    arrayify_param!(str)
    str.each { |st| p st }

    # I know I can do it like this
    str = 'abc'
    [*str].each { |st| p st} # this will have issue when parse a hash value

    # or
    str = str.is_a?(Arrray) ? str : [str]
    str.each { |st| p st}
```

I want to define the arrayify_param! method as a before filter so that I can use parameters directory in next steps. I have searched for this, but haven't find a good solution, the method I want has change the parameter's type, but I don't know how to implement it. Could you help me...

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but check out `Kernal#Array`: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-Array

Comment: @LoganSerman I haven't find `Kernal#Array` methods helps to solve this issue. If there is any method names `arrayify!` in kernal will help me :)

Comment: The banged signature you’ve posted assumes that the `param` parameter would be internally change it’s type. It is impossible in ruby.

Comment: @mudasobwa Thanks for the comment, I will find another way to implement it.